# C# WebBrowser - Manipulate Forms

Tags: c#

Just wondering, if I load a site such as Facebook into a WebBrowser control how do I enter data into the form controls from WF/Desktop app?

Do I have to use the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property.  The MSDN documentation has a good example on how to use it, the code is very similar to DOM manipulation you would've seen in Javascript.

Comment: Was just looking at that :)

Is it possible to invoke the click of a button?

Comment: This code appears to be able to do it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2eed72f7-4fde-4730-abf7-738e9b6e87c4